# Several problems with the Objective-C ARC conversion

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to convert my code to Objective-C ARC and get several errors.

1.:

```
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPathApply(pathRef,  path, CGPathCallback); //error
```

It says: Implicit conversion of an Objective.C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC

2.:

```
static void CGPathCallback(void *info, const CGPathElement *element) {
NSBezierPath *path = info; //error
[…] }
```

It says: Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'void *' to 'NSBezierPath *' is disallowed with ARC

Any ideas, how I can resolve the problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [bridged casts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts). In this case, you just want the simple `__bridge` modifier, e.g.

```
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPathApply(pathRef, (__bridge void *)path, CGPathCallback);
```

and

```
static void CGPathCallback(void *info, const CGPathElement *element) {
    NSBezierPath *path = (__bridge NSBezierPath*)info;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The second code works, but your first solution doesn't work. I get: Passing 'CGPathRef' (aka 'const struct CGPath *) to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers.

Comment: @Flocked: Sorry, I didn't realize that was a `void*` parameter. You can just use `(__bridge void *)`, and I'll update my answer to reflect that.